# Libor Market Model with SABR Calibration

Tags: option-pricing, stochastic-volatility, calibration

What is the industry practice in calibrating SABR Libor Market Model? Do you first calibrate the SABR model using market data and then implement the libor market model with the calibrated parameters?

I am reading a paper from Hagan and Lesniewski "*LIBOR market model with SABR style stochastic volatility*" and the paper provides a closed form approximation for swaption vol in SABR/LMM. It is more complex with the introduction of kernels. I am not able to find any implementation online using Hagan and Lesniewski's paper. Anyone calibrates SABR/LMM model using this approach?

Comment: Now you need to allow negative interest rates.

Comment: Right, I know people using Normal or Displaced Diffusion Libor Market Model to deal with negative rates. These are local volatility models. Is there any derivation of shifted SABR/LMM to allow negative interest rates?

Comment: For negative rates, you may like Antonov, Konikov,  Spector https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2653682 (following https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2557046 ) Also you may want to look at Brigo forward markets model (FMM) https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3330240 - going from forward-looking to reset n arrears (such as SOFR).

Comment: Apologies, the FMM paper is Lyashenko and Mercurio, not Brigo.

Comment: The book:  Christian Crispoldi, Gérald Wigger, Peter Larkin SABR and SABR LIBOR Market Models in Practice: With Examples Implemented in Python (2015) https://www.amazon.com/dp/1137378638/ ; https://link.springer.com/book/10.1057%2F9781137378644 has some Python examples.